Disable TwentyTwentyFive styles in site editor
I would like to use TwentyTwentyFive theme as a parent theme and have created a child theme. I would like to disable the default styles inside the the folder twentytwentyfive/styles/*.json and twentytwentyfive/colors/*.json. How can I do that inside the child theme or in a plugin?

I noticed that the colors json files are inside a subfolder like this: twentytwentyfive/styles/colors/*.json

Do you want to replace colors?

@gael well yes, I would like to use TwentyTwentyFive and have full control over the styles in the site editor and then add my own. I am aware that it is possible to add my own styles, but I cannot find a way to remove the default styles that comes with TwentyTwentyFive. I feel delivering a new website to a client, that gives the option to see color palettes and styles, that are not relevant to the website I am delivering.

To disable the default styles in Twenty Twenty-Five theme and use your child theme styles, you can follow a simpler approach without overcomplicating it.
Recommended Approach:
Learn the Basics: Follow the Develop Your First Low-Code Block Theme course. It explains how to properly create and manage a block theme child.
Use the "Create Block Theme" Plugin:
Install and activate the Create Block Theme plugin.
Use this plugin to create a child theme from Twenty Twenty-Five.
Once the child theme is created, you can modify or replace the theme.json file in your child theme to control styles and settings.
Disabling Parent Styles:
To override or disable the styles from the parent theme, simply create your own theme.json in the child theme. WordPress will prioritize the child theme’s theme.json.
This is the cleanest and most future-proof way to manage a child theme for block-based themes like Twenty Twenty-Five.
